# VLOOKUP to only fetch the right X Characters

Tags: excel

I am trying a VLOOKUP function in excel 2010. However, when it returns the results, I am trying to eliminate the first couple characters from the resulting column. When I use the RIGHT or LEFT functions within the VLOOKUP, it doenst work.

Anything I am doing wrong? Or any suggestions would help. Alternatively, I have copied the data as text into another column and removed the unwanted information.

```
=VLOOKUP(A27,Sheet2!$A:$L,RIGHT(5,2),FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=RIGHT(VLOOKUP(A27,Sheet2!$A:$L,5,FALSE),2)
```